# Git rebase, squashing two commits and keep everting all as it is

Tags: git, rebase, squash

Hello I have this type of situation

- 13f5337 100
- c8fw28f 99
- 3554tb0 98
- 2321dsw 97
- a551654 96
- 41c990d 95
- 1343756 94toxic data Fixed
- 96236fb 93toxic data
- 8894377 92
- 94t6ff1 91
- dda323w 1

I am trying to squash commit 94 and 95 so toxic data is not visible any more, but every time I try i am squashing everting from 95 to 100...and i am leaving pick on commits 95, 96, 97, 98, 99.

Comment: AFAIK squashing commits won't remove the "toxic data".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to squash the toxic data commit and the fix commit so that they don’t show up as separate commits in your git history.

If that’s the case, then I would run `git rebase -i 8894377` (SHA for commit 92) and when presented with the list of commits, squash ONLY 94 and 95 while picking the rest of your commits.

After you are done choosing which commits to squash, save the changes and git will give you a chance to write a commit message for the new commit where 93, 94 and 95 will be squashed.